# Why is Ionic 5 using Angular 8.2.14

Tags: ionic-framework

I updated to the latest ionic cli (version 6.1.0). And when I create a new ionic project, in the package.json file it uses angular 8.2.14.
Why is that so? Isn't ionic 5 using angular 9?

Answer (score 3):

**There are not major changes in Angular 9.**

A9 is similar to A8 (as per functionality and logic). 
Angular 9 is in latest version and it's now stable.

*I think Ionic decided to use Angular 8 because it's LTS version.*

*Other reaseon can be, Ionic 5 was launched some days before Angular released its version  9.*

Here you can read some notes:
https://angular.io/guide/releases#deprecation-practices

You can update easily your ionic project angular version to 9 (it's 100% compattible with ionic) if you want to use the latest version.

```
ng update @angular/core @angular/cli.
```

**The starter apps currently ship with Angular 8 and will be updated to ship with Angular 9 by default soon.** (source: Ionic Forum)